# android thousands separator and two decimals

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'd like some help as I can't get what I need to work in android studio.

I have an EditText that I want to separate by commas into thousands as the user writes (onTextChange), at the same time limiting it to 2 or 8 decimal places.

Until now I have been able to separate the input into thousands by placing "," I have also been able to limit the number of decimal places with InputFilter but each one separately, I cannot perform a set of both actions, thousands separator "," and limit the number of decimal places . Could someone help me with this?

**with the following I get the thousands separator**

```
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class NumberTextWatcherForThousand implements TextWatcher {

    EditText editText;


    public NumberTextWatcherForThousand(EditText editText) {
        this.editText = editText;


    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        try
        {
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            String value = editText.getText().toString();


            if (value != null && !value.equals(""))
            {

                if(value.startsWith(".")){
                    editText.setText("0.");
                }
                if(value.startsWith("0") && !value.startsWith("0.")){
                    editText.setText("");

                }


                String str = editText.getText().toString().replaceAll(",", "");

                if (!value.equals(""))
                    editText.setText(getDecimalFormattedString(str));
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
            }
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }

    }

    public static String getDecimalFormattedString(String value)
    {
        StringTokenizer lst = new StringTokenizer(value, ".");
        String str1 = value;
        String str2 = "";
        if (lst.countTokens() > 1)
        {
            str1 = lst.nextToken();
            str2 = lst.nextToken();
        }
        String str3 = "";
        int i = 0;
        int j = -1 + str1.length();
        if (str1.charAt( -1 + str1.length()) == '.')
        {
            j--;
            str3 = ".";
        }
        for (int k = j;; k--)
        {
            if (k < 0)
            {
                if (str2.length() > 0)
                    str3 = str3 + "." + str2;
                return str3;
            }
            if (i == 3)
            {
                str3 = "," + str3;
                i = 0;
            }
            str3 = str1.charAt(k) + str3;
            i++;
        }

    }

    public static String trimCommaOfString(String string) {
//        String returnString;
        if(string.contains(",")){
            return string.replace(",","");}
        else {
            return string;
        }

    }

}
```

**with this I limit the decimals**

```
public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {

    Pattern mPattern;

    public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsBeforeZero,int digitsAfterZero) {
        mPattern=Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0," + (digitsBeforeZero-1) + "}+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero-1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        Matcher matcher=mPattern.matcher(dest);
        if(!matcher.matches())
            return "";
        return null;
    }

}

public static Double formatdecimal(Double num, Integer numdecimal) {
    return Math.round(num* Math.pow(10, numdecimal)) / Math.pow(10, numdecimal);
}
```

the first works to separate the thousands, the second to limit the decimals, but I can't find how to do what I need, I want to limit the decimals and separate by thousands

Comment: please post what you have tried so far

Comment: ready, I have added what I have